# How to hash int/long using hashlib in Python?

Tags: python, hash, cryptography

I'm developing a set of cryptographic algorithms / protocols for educational purposes. Specifically, I am currently working on OAEP encoding.

OAEP involves use of cryptographic hash functions; therefore I wanted to use the `hashlib` library, provided in the standard of Python3.

Let's say, I have a 128-bit integer, for which I want to get the SHA256 digest of. How can I do this in Python? All I could found was how to hash strings (or b-strings) with `hashlib.sha256()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hashes work on *bytes*, a sequence of integer values in the range 0-255; this is independent of the implementation language. You'd have to convert your 128-bit integer into a series of bytes representing that value. That's why the `hashlib` module only accepts `bytes` objects ("`b` values").

How you do this is entirely dependent on the use case; you'd need to see how the specific OAEP standard specifies how such an integer is represented.

For example, you could take the string representation of the decimal integer value; a sequence of ASCII digits; this is not a very efficient method as that can take up to 39 bytes:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> 2 ** 128 - 1  # largest 128-bit value
340282366920938463463374607431768211455
>>> len(str(2 ** 128 - 1))
39
>>> str(2 ** 128 - 1).encode('ASCII')  # ascii bytes
b'340282366920938463463374607431768211455'
>>> hashlib.sha256(str(2 ** 128 - 1).encode('ASCII')).hexdigest()
'f315ff319bf588e202110ab686fb8c3dbca12b4df9fbd844615b566a2fff3e75'
```

A much more efficient method would be to take those 128 bits, divide them into 16 bytes and hash those. You then need to decide on [byte order (little or big endian)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). If you need to hash multiple integer values, then the Python [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) can help with producing the bytes, but only for integer values up to 8 bytes (you'd have to split up your larger numbers first). For single values, just use the [`int.to_bytes()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes):

```
>>> (2 ** 128 - 1).to_bytes(16, 'little', signed=False)
b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
>>> hashlib.sha256((2 ** 128 - 1).to_bytes(16, 'little', signed=False)).hexdigest()
'5ac6a5945f16500911219129984ba8b387a06f24fe383ce4e81a73294065461b'
```

Comment: I understand that; however, an integer is still a series of bytes. I.e. 3 = 00000011 or 16 = 00010000 (or longer integers are just longer series of bits which can be divided into blocks of 8). What I don't understand is, how I should feed this integer into Python's hashlib.sha256() implementation. I do not understand what it expects as argument.

Comment: @OranCanÖren: that's what my answer tries to convey to you. You **represent** the numeric value as bytes, and how you do that depends on your use case. The standard would detail what method to use.

Answer (score -1):

I used https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/hash/keccak.html
keccak library to deal with integers.
Example :

```
keccak_hash = keccak.new(digest_bits=256)
bytes_len = (len(hex(integer val))-2) // 2
keccak_hash.update(<integer val>.to_bytes(bytes_len, byteorder ='big'))
return keccak_hash.digest()
```

Once the leaves (integer) are hashed, subsequent calls to keccak_hash.update() can be directly fed with previous hash output (which is in bytes)

```
keccak_hash.update(<bytes>)
```