# hash each number of number list to sha256 with hashlib python

Tags: python, passwords, sha256, hashlib

My hashes are different with standard sha256

How can I hash each list number to sha256 with hashlib in python?

you can see my result and other online converter results:

```
#hash 9999 from https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html
    
    888df25ae35772424a560c7152a1de794440e0ea5cfee62828333a456a506e05
    
#hash 9999 from https://www.online-convert.com/result#j=96f7a8bb-2c97-4c6c-ae6d-7deda4f62e3c

    888df25ae35772424a560c7152a1de794440e0ea5cfee62828333a456a506e05

#hash 9999 from https://passwordsgenerator.net/sha256-hash-generator/

    888DF25AE35772424A560C7152A1DE794440E0EA5CFEE62828333A456A506E05





my sha256 hash of 9999:

       
    877f59e9e62b9f0bfdc877653856410990e8aba4ac8b55ad06cd8cf5ecdfbc17
```

this is my code. Anyone can teach me how I can fix that?

```
import CSV
from hashlib import sha256

hash_dic = {}
numbers = []
count = 1

#make number range between 1 t0 9999
while count <= 9999:
    numbers.append(count)
    count += 1

#make hash sha256 dic
for number in numbers:
    hashed = sha256(bytes(number)).hexdigest()
    hash_dic[number] = hashed


#open csv file and maining hashes
with open("Desktop/passwords.csv") as passwrd:
    reader = csv.reader(passwrd)
    for row in reader:
        csv_hash = row[1]
        
        for key,value in hash_dic.items():
            if csv_hash == value:
                print(f"for {row[0]} password is {key}")
            else:
                pass

print(hash_dic)
#print(number)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the online sites you mentioned, you are inputting a string `'9999'`, probably in ASCII or UTF8. You need to pass the same byte array to the hashlib.

```py
import hashlib
hashlib.sha256(str(9999).encode()).hexdigest()
# --> 888df25ae35772424a560c7152a1de794440e0ea5cfee62828333a456a506e05
```

If you really want to pass an integer as its byte representation, not as a string, then [How to hash int/long using hashlib in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48367035/how-to-hash-int-long-using-hashlib-in-python) will help.